# Develop with the assembly but ship without the assembly

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, deployment, .net-assembly

I work for a client named BigClient. The machines in BigClient are installed with a service software called BigSoftware. But my compute is not installed with this BigSoftware. So when I develop an application that runs on top of this BigSoftware, I need to rip out an assembly file called TinyDll.dll from the lib folder of this BigSoftware, and copy it to my computer and reference it from there. So here comes the question, how should I write my code and config my visual studio (C#) to achieve:

1. when I deploy in BigClient, I should not ship this TinyDll.dll with my application. My application should load this TinyDll.dll from the global assembly cache on their machines.
2. when I deploy locally on my computer, my application should reference this TinyDll.dll from my local folder.

Edit: Finally I figured out I just need the TinyDll.dll for compiling my solution. But this TinyDll.dll should not be included as part of my deployment (because otherwise I violate the licensing agreement). Then my deployed application will automatically load it from GAC.

Comment: You don't have question... 1/2 seem to be valid reasonable statements, so not sure what you are looking for... (Note that in most cases just copying TinyDll.Dll locally will only let you build code, not test it - i.e. in case of SharePoint)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If I build my solution with TinyDll.dll and then ship it without TinyDll.dll, would my application automatically load TinyDll.dll from BigClient's machines' global assembly cache?

Comment: Obviously assembly from GAC will be loaded irrespective if you have one locally or not. So it does not really matter if "TinyDll" is shipped with your code or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK. Thanks! I also confirmed the case when TinyDll is not shipped along with, my application will load TinyDll from GAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods and best practices around dynamic assembly loading you could do but with most development environment type problems I like to look at process first before writing code that just helps you write code.

The solution that sticks out to me is: place this TinyDll.dll in your local dev machine GAC. Then your solution will load it from the same place no matter what.

Comment: There are many Dev machines and I can't copy TinyDll.dll to each of them. Hmm, but this inspired me. I should firstly check GAC and use the dll from GAC if any version exists in GAC. If not, I would check local folder and load the dll from there.